# Character restriction at grep in Adobe Indesign CC 2014 on Windows

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

When I use the grep functionality in Indesign CC 2014 on Windows it doesn't return the same amount of results.
It only happens on Windows in the latest version of Indesign.

For example: 
when i use the grep `<fn>[^<]+</fn>` on windows it wil find `<fn>lorem ipsum</fn>`, but it refuses to find any text between the fn-tags that is larger then 1024 characters (i think it is 1024 but i am not sure).

Is anyone experiencing the same problem or even have a solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the case in ID CC 2014.1 (WIN) as well.

However, it doesn't seem to be related to the number of characters, but to the number of paragraphs. If the search's result spanned two or more paragraphs, InDesign doesn't find the string reliably any more.

Comment: I reported it as a bug to Adobe and after some mails I've send a video. They will investigate it and I hope this will be solved soon.